# PrintWriter doesn't output all characters

Tags: java, barcode, checksum, jfilechooser, printwriter

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Open file containing names with FileChooser dialog
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( );
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File fileObj = chooser.getSelectedFile( );

    // Read names and write greetings, each in their own file.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(fileObj);
    PrintWriter pw;
    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("labels.txt"));
    while (in.hasNextLine( )) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[ ] fields = line.split(",");
        String name = fields[0];
        String address = fields[1];
        String city = fields[2];
        String state = fields[3];
        String zipcode = fields[4];

        pw.println(name);
        pw.println(address);
        pw.println(city + ", " + state + " " + zipcode);
        pw.println(getBarCode(zipcode));
        pw.println();
    }
    in.close( );
    pw.close( );
}

public static int returnChecksum(String zipcode) {

    int sumOfDigits = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int checksum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < zipcode.length(); i++) {
        if (zipcode.charAt(i) != '-'){
            value = Integer.parseInt(
                    zipcode.substring(i,  (i + 1)));
            sumOfDigits += value;
        }
    }
    checksum = (10 - sumOfDigits % 10) % 10;
    return checksum;
}

public static String getBarCode(String zipcode)  {
    String chars = " 1234567890-";
    String[ ] codes = {"   ", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|",
            ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::", "||:::" , ""};
    String retVal = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < zipcode.length( ); i++) {
        char c = zipcode.charAt(i);
        int index = chars.indexOf(c);
        String code = codes[index];
        retVal += code ;
    }
    retVal += codes[returnChecksum(zipcode)];

    return "|" + retVal  + "|";
}
```

My problem is that one of the addresses I'm reading turns out a checksum of 0 and does not output it to the `labels.txt` file completely. It turns out like:

```
Meredith Baker
1343 Maple Avenue
Denver, CO 80236-2982
||::|:||:::::|:|::||::||::::|:||:|::|::|:::|:|   |
```

When I need it to turn out like this:

```
Meredith Baker
1343 Maple Avenue
Denver, CO 80236-2982
||::|:||:::::|:|::||::||::::|:||:|::|::|:::|:|||:::|
```

Everything else is perfect, all of the other addresses output just like how I want it, but it's just that one detail that's missing and it's bugging me.

Comment: If checksum is 0 for zipcode, then value from 0 index form `codes` array is returned. That value consists of spaces. So output looks OK. It would be useful if you provide both actual and expected outputs in the question

Comment: `retVal += codes[chars.indexOf(returnChecksum(zipcode))];` But converting the returned value to char.

Answer (score 0):

If `returnChecksum()` returns `0`, then `codes[0] = "   "`. But you want the string that corresponds to the index of the char '0' in the `chars` array. So use `indexOf` as you did with the other chars. Here's the long version - you can simplify it:

```
// 0 <= checksum <= 9
int checksum = returnChecksum(zipcode);
// Convert single digit number to char
char checksumAsChar = Integer.toString(checksum).charAt(0);
// Find in string. 1 <= index <= 10
int index = chars.indexOf(checksumAsChar);
retVal += codes[index];
```

It might just be easier to re-arrange:

```
String chars = "0123456789-";
String[ ] codes = {"|:|::", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|",
        ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "||:::" };
```